# Is there any widget in GWT for generating Barcode?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2, gxt

I want to generate barcode using a widget in GWT. Is it possible? If it is. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There's no existing widget, but you can take a look at the [zxing API for 1D and 2D barcodes](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and implement such a widget.